# Date format needed to work 'order by date' query in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, sqlite

I am storing list of data in **sqlite for my iOS app**. In DB one column 'addedOn' stores dates from **server response in format '30-Jul-2014 07:43:20'.** 
Here I have tried many things on 'addedOn' column but could not fetch date in ASC/DESC order.
Some other details are

1. Column 'addedOn' date type is DATETIME.
2. Queries tried to fetch in DESC used are:

`"SELECT * FROM tableName  ORDER BY datetime(addedOn) DESC LIMIT 1" 
 & "SELECT * FROM tableName  ORDER BY date(addedOn) DESC LIMIT 1" & "SELECT * FROM tableName  ORDER BY addedOn DESC LIMIT 1".`

But all these queries failed to give me expected result.

3. I tried to convert this date in another format while inserting in DB it self but converting of this date format in other date format like `'yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss'` isn't working at all. **For that tried below code:**

   NSString *dateString = @"30-Jul-2014 07:43:20";
       NSDateFormatter *dateFormatter = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
       [dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
       NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
       dateFromString = [dateFormatter dateFromString:dateString];

   ```
   NSString *stringDate = [dateFormatter stringFromDate:dateFromString];
   NSLog(@"stringDate %@", stringDate);
   ```

So my question is this possible to convert this type format in any other format or is there any thing else that I am missing. Please share your thought and suggest me the changes that I need to do. Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks folks for your time and suggesting me changes that I need to do. 
**Storing of NSDate as it is in DB instead of Converting NSDate in NSString and then inserting in DB solved my problem with little change in code**

There are two cases in which my code works now

```
NSString *dateString = MD_history.addedOn;
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

And

```
NSString *dateString = MD_history.addedOn;
NSDateFormatter *df = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
NSLocale *usLocale = [[NSLocale alloc] initWithLocaleIdentifier:@"en_US"];
[df setLocale:usLocale];
[df setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];
NSDate *dateFromString = [[NSDate alloc] init];
dateFromString = [df dateFromString:dateString];
```

In this case Date after inserting in DB is in "2014-07-30 02:13:20 +0000" format. In this sorting of date column works proper.

Answer (score 1):

Your dataFormat seems to be wrong. Try the following DateFormat.

```
[dateFormatter setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormatter dateFromString:yourDateString];
```

This will give you exact date.

Hope it helps..

Comment: Balaji Thanks but here insertions works properly but fetching of date in ASC/DESC order fails, I have tried with queries mentioned above but all three of them doesn't give me expected result. Is there anything that need to change in query.

Comment: I think you don't need to change anything when retrieving. You just the change the dateFormat string. Then try inserting it to DB. Hope it will work...

Answer (score 1):

```
NSSortDescriptor *sortDescriptor = [[NSSortDescriptor alloc] initWithKey:@"creationDate" ascending:YES];
```

try NSPredict and use the above code

Answer (score 1):

I have my DB with SQLite & have date in format "dd-mmm-yyyy HH:mm:ss" 
in which the below query works..

**SELECT * FROM TableName ORDER BY addedOn ASC**

ASC|DESC can be used as per requirement..

And if you want to convert your date format than do as under :

```
NSString * dateStr = @"30-Jul-2014 07:43:20";
NSDateFormatter *dateFormat = [[NSDateFormatter alloc]init];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"dd-MMM-yyyy HH:mm:ss"];

NSDate *date = [dateFormat dateFromString:dateStr];
[dateFormat setDateFormat:@"yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"];
NSString *finalString = [dateFormat stringFromDate:date];
```

here the output is finalString = "2014-07-30 07:43:20"